# Rodar App em background com phonegap

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Sou programador PHP e estou me aventurando no mundo mobile.

Preciso criar um app simples, irá apenas tocar uma radio especifica, o problema é: Como rodar o app em backgroud? Quando o app for minimizado a radio precisa continuar tocando.

Não preciso de código pronto, o caminho das pedras serve.

Comment: Vc já fez um código que toca uma rádio e quando vc minimiza ele para de tocar, é isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desenvolvo para Android e se fosse usando código nativo iria te sugerir o uso de `IntentService` no Android ([Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) e [create-service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)).

Pesquisando sobre o uso de `Services` no Phonegap, não sei se é possível ter um `Service` com código nativo Android e que executasse o seu código JavaScript para tocar a rádio.

Uma alternativa é buscar um plugin do PhoneGap (nunca usei, logo não posso indicar nenhum). Mas pesquisando por alto existem esses plugins: [BackgroundService](https://github.com/Red-Folder/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService) e [Phonegap Android Background Service Plugin - Explained](http://red-folder.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/phonegap-android-background-service_11.html). Se alguém que já teve experiência puder dar mais detalhes seria perfeito.

Espero ter ajudado.